# timer_create how to stop recursive thread function invocation after first timer expiry?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I have created a timer using the simple "timer_create". The timer is created using SIGEV_THREAD. That is when the timer expires, there is a call to the timer thread function.

**How timer_create works is, suppose assume: `expiry=3` secs and `timer interval is 1 ns`, then the timer keeps ticking every 1 ns until expiry reaches. Once the timer expires, from that instance it keeps on hitting the timer thread function after every 1 ns (timer interval). And keeps on creating one thread per hit till the timer is deleted.**

I don't want this to happen, i want once the timer expires, it should go and hit the thread function only once.

How can i achieve this? Can we put any option in timer_create? If not any other timer API?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is an implementation flaw in the glibc implementation of POSIX timers. There is certainly no way the `timer_getoverrun` function, which is critical for realtime usage, can work in the glibc implementation, since it returns from the kernel the overrun count for the "current" expiration, but when multiple expiration events are running in parallel, "current" makes no sense. There are also serious issues with resource exhaustion and dropped expiration events which make the implementation unusable for realtime purposes. For example, in `nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_routines.c`:

```
struct thread_start_data *td = malloc (sizeof (*td));

/* There is not much we can do if the allocation fails.  */
...
```

In the Linux man page for [`sigevent`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/sigevent.7.html), you see for `SIGEV_THREAD`:

> Among the implementation possibilities here are that each timer notification could result in the creation of a new thread, or that a single thread is created to receive all notifications.

The latter is the only choice that could provide correct realtime semantics, but for some reason, glibc did not take this choice.

Here is a possible workaround:

Choose a realtime signal, block that signal before creating any threads, and setup your timer to use that signal with `SIGEV_SIGNAL`. Now, create a thread for handling your timer(s), and loop on `sigwaitinfo`, then call your handler function each time it returns. This is actually one possible implementation (and the most-correct implementation) of `SIGEV_THREAD` which glibc *should* be using.

Another possibility: there is exactly one synchronization-related, non-syscall-invoking, async-signal-safe function in POSIX: `sem_post`. Thus it may be possible to make a signal handler (as opposed to getting the signal from `sigwaitinfo`) synchronize with another thread for the purpose of delivering timer events. But I haven't worked out the details, and it seems like it may be difficult or impossible still.

Comment: This is a serious implementation flaw from glibc, really. Your solution looks good, but we can't use signals. This is a tool and design requirement. Do you have any other options? Can't we put any option, while setting the timer, where we can specify the number of threads?

Comment: No, there is no such option. Another workaround would be to forget about timers and simply create a thread that repeatedly sleeps until a given *absolute* time (you need to use absolute times rather than relative to avoid error accumulation), and reads the current time to count overruns manually. `clock_nanosleep` has this functionality. With 1ns timer though you won't end up sleeping at all, and you'll have at least 5000-10000 overruns per expiration you manage to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Just set timer interval to 0 and expiry to whatever you want. Your timer will expire once (and thread created and run) and then stay disarmed.

Comment: Are you sure? A timer is started and armed only once. Once started, we can't re-do a settime otherwise it gets failed.

Comment: the way timers work is that expiry is counted down to zero, then the timer triggers and then the interval is copied to expiry and the whole thing starts again.

So, to do a one shot time, which is my understanding of what you want, program the expiry to what you need and set interval to zero. The timer will count from expiry till zero, will fire once and then be disabled.

At this point you should be able to use settime to reprogram it again.

Was that what you wanted?